# Xcode Search Bar - Can't search through NSObjects containing NSStrings

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsobject, searchbar, nsrange

So I'm adding a search bar to my custom tableview with custom cells, and it's giving an error.

> -[Game rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170244e60
>   2016-10-15 15:41:49.557956 CustomCellApp[25930:7889617]
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Game rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170244e60

I'm populating my tableview by an array containing NSObjects which contain strings (gamesArray)and those strings I'm getting it from a JSON array (jsonArray), all from a php file connecting to a MYSQL server which have all the strings.

**Here is the code for the search bar:**

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

if (searchText.length == 0) {
    isFiltered = NO;
} else {
    isFiltered = YES;
    filteredGamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // ----- Problem Method ----- //
    for (NSString *str in gamesArray) {

        // ----- Crashes Here ----- //
        NSRange stringRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (stringRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [filteredGamesArray addObject:str];
        }
    }
    // ------------------------------------ //
}
[myTableView reloadData];
}
```

**Here is the code for the tableView:**

```
// Configuring the cell
Game * gameObject;

// Showing either Normal List or Filtered List
if (!isFiltered) {
    gameObject = [gamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else {
    gameObject = [filteredGamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

**Here is the code from server**
It adds the strings from the server to a jsonarray which is then added to an NSObject to an array called gamesArray

```
    NSString * gID = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString * gName = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"gameName"];
    NSString * gLabel1 = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"gameLabel1"];
    NSString * gLabel2 = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"gameLabel2"];
    NSString * gLabel3 = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"gameLabel3"];
```

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!
How can I fix this? Any ideas? Thank you**

I think the problem is that when searching, the program is seeing that it has an array to search through, gamesArray, but when going inside it has 5 NSObjects, each containing strings, so it's not working because it doesn't know what to do.

As a solution, how can I make it that the search bar searches through the **gamesArray**, **directly at 1 NSObject**, the **gameName** , reading all the strings in that NSObject which is called **gName**

For example, this piece of code targets a specific NSObject inside the gamesArray

```
[[gamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"gameName"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is: objects in games array are not strings, they are Game objects.

```
for (Game *game in gamesArray) {
    NSString *str = game.fieldOfInterest;

    // ----- Crashes Here ----- //
    NSRange stringRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (stringRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        [filteredGamesArray addObject:game];
    }
}
```

This should address the issue of your crash. If the search behavior is not correct, please ask a new question related to your new issue. As a best guess, I would suggest you inspect your table delegate methods for how they behave when filtered is true.

Comment: Okay beautiful part of it worked, I don't get the error anymore, BUT no matter what I search only the first game from the tableview shows up. Any ideas? Thank you btw

Comment: If this code fixed the problem in the question, would you mind accepting it? The problem in your comment is a different issue, and likely related to code not shown in the question above. I would recommend debugging and inspecting the contents of filteredGamesArray at different points in the search execution.